# Handlebars precompiled to plain HTML

Tags: node.js, typescript, handlebars.js

Is there a way to precompile a Handlebars template to plain HTML? Handlebars precompile produces a js file. Can I run that JS on node to produce a HTML file? This is how I'm trying:

```
// Get a Handlebars instance
var hb = require("handlebars");

// Load a template
import fs = require('fs');
var template:string = fs.readFileSync('templates/template.handlebars','utf8');

// Compile said template
var compiled = hb.precompile(template);

// Write JS file
fs.writeFileSync('compiled/template.js', compiled);

var test = compiled.main();

// Write HTML file
fs.writeFileSync('compiled/template.html', test);
```

This fails as compiled.main is not a function. There's a main function in there though, which I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution. You don't precompile, you just compile and then run the compiled template:

```
// Get a Handlebars instance
var hb = require("handlebars");

// Load a template
import fs = require('fs');
var template:string = fs.readFileSync('templates/template.handlebars','utf8');

// Compile said template
var compiled = hb.compile(template);
var html = compiled({});

// Write HTML file
fs.writeFileSync('compiled/template.html', html);
```

Pity it isn't in the docs.

Comment: Then please accept your answer :) Thanks for sharing

Comment: Will do, but can't till tomorrow!

Comment: The documentation is truly confusing, I wish someone with deep knowledge of how Handlebars works would help by updating them with more details.